# email header parser

Tags: c#, email, parsing

i want to parse the header of the bounced email. i have tried to use some open source email parser but did not find any email parser that can parse email header
thanx

Comment: What technology do you want to use to accomplish this?

Comment: i want to use asp.net with c#

Comment: And where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: the parser i have tried all give the total email as a single string. i want to know is there any way to get all these parts separatelly.

Comment: ever find a solution to this Philip?  I'm trying to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SmtpClient to send email have a look at the code example for [SmtpFailedRecipientsException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception.aspx) in the MSDN.